# CSS Media query element are stick to the bottom

Tags: html, css, overflow

i have a problem with my media queries css's code, indeed i have an overflow problem with my container overflowing body's container and i don't know why, Here is the link to my website so you can visualize : [Website](https://dieriba.github.io/GRID-CSS-HTML-JUNIO-CHALLENGE/)

The things is  that I want to move the container up, so the last block called kira is not stick to the bottom of the page but i don't know how to make that happens, i've already tried with margin-top but nothing's work, mozila dev tools told me that there is an overflow problem with body element maybe this is the reason I can't.

Here is my css code :

```
*{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* BODY TAG */
body{
font-family: 'Barlow Semi Condensed', sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
display: flex;
height: 100vh;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
/* END BODY TAG */
/* CONTAINER CLASS */
.container{
max-width: 1200px;
height: 600px;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-areas: 
"daniel daniel jonathan kira"
"jeanette patrick patrick kira";
grid-gap: 30px;

}
/* END CONTAINER CLASS */



/* MEDIA QUERY */
@media(max-width:480px){
.container{
    
    margin-top: -100px;
    width: 300px;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 2fr 1fr 1fr 2fr 2fr ;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "daniel"
    "jonathan"
    "jeanette"
    "patrick"
    "kira";
}
.daniel{
    grid-area: daniel;
}
.jonathan{
    grid-area: jonathan;
}
.kira{
    grid-area: kira;
}
.jeanette{
    grid-area: jeanette;
}
.patrick{
    grid-area: patrick;
}
}

/* TABLETTE QUERY */
@media(max-width:1024px) and (min-width:480px){
.container{
    
    max-width: 700px;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 2fr 1fr 1fr 2fr 2fr ;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "daniel"
    "jonathan"
    "jeanette"
    "patrick"
    "kira";
}
.daniel{
    grid-area: daniel;
}
.jonathan{
    grid-area: jonathan;
}
.kira{
    grid-area: kira;
}
.jeanette{
    grid-area: jeanette;
}
.patrick{
    grid-area: patrick;
}
}
/* END TABLETTE QUERY */

/* END MEDIA QUERY */
```

Comment: the kira container seems to be on the right side. can you specify more what do you want to do with it?

Comment: oh i did not specify, kira is in the good place in the 1024px width and more, but when it comes to mobile width (under 480px), kira is stick to the bottom of the page and I don't know why, I want to move up the container in the mobile width so kira is not stick to the bottom of the page

Comment: Hi i found something ineresting. The kira is on the bottom cuz its the last of the divs. the body container does not have good overflow properties. I tried using the `overflow: auto;` and it worked, so the body container does hold all of the blocks. The only problem is that it added a scrollbar. Ii hope its acceptable for you

Answer (score 1):

There is a `height:600px` set on the `container` div and a `height:100vh` set on the `body`. Both these heights are not enough to "hold" all the content. So the content overflows and since there is no padding on the container, the last div is positioned until the end of the page. You can remove the `height` for both the `container` div and the `body` and use `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` on one of them.